# System.Data.SqlClient assembly not found .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am trying my hand at converting a VB.net application over to C#, and I got to the part where I was doing the database portion with the SqlClient, and it just isn’t there. most of the posts I’ve found say I should use the nuget package, but when I did that, it failed because I am targeting .net 3.5 This is a requirement because until we get rid (slowly) of all of our windows 7 machines, that’s what I have to target.

EDIT a screenshot of my reference manager, also i am using System.Data
[image]

Comment: Just FYI - Windows 7 supports .Net 4.0 and above.  Even XP supports .Net 4.0.  You can go up to 4.6 on Vista. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements

Comment: I dont know what the patching level is on the machines sadly, i know that they are older thin clients.

Comment: in .NET 3.5: SqlClient is *in* System.Data

Answer (score 6):

If you're targeting .NET 3.5, you can use a *framework reference* to `System.Data`, which gives you `SqlClient`. However, you *probably shouldn't* still keep trying to work with .NET 3.5. You won't be able to use the nuget package, because it doesn't go back that far. In csproj terms, this is:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.Data" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: `However, you probably shouldn't still keep trying to work with .NET 3.5` - Can you help me convince my managers? ;)

Comment: I was getting advice from some guys on the Rubber Duck team at the same time i posted this, it seems i needed System.Data.Entity as well.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb you jest, but I'm actively trying, which is why I've recently dropped down-level TFMs from a number of libraries that I manage; I had *hoped* to make netstandard2.0 the minimum supported version, but problems with .NET 4.6.1 *claiming* to support netstandard2.0 (but kinda not really) mean that I've had to multi-target with netstandard2.0 + net461 as the bottom of the pile. I'm not alone in this direction - I've seen multiple library maintainers do the same. So: tell your managers "no more library support"